# matlab mod() function gives wrong answers

Tags: matlab

I was trying to use Matlab to solve some problem and store the result when dt*j are integers,
using the following code.

```
j=1;
dt = 1E-05;
a=[];
while dt*j <=20
    if mod(dt*j,1) ==0
        a=[a;[dt*j,j]];
    end
j=j+1;
end
```

But Matlab gives me incorrect results. Some integers(3,6,7,11,etc...) are missing as shown below.

```
a =
1      100000
2      200000
4      400000
5      500000
8      800000
9      900000
10     1000000
16     1600000
17     1700000
18     1800000
19     1900000
20     2000000
```

I tried this again using dt=1E-4 and it gives the correct result. Could anyone tell me what is going on here? Thank you.

Comment: Another example of floating point precision errors. It`s not `mod` that's wrong, `dt*j` is not precisely the expected value.

Comment: yes, dt*300000==3 ans = 0 but dt*400000==4, ans = 1 I was confused because only some numbers are missing, but I guess it relates to how computer store number

Comment: It's a question of floating point arithmetic. There are some problems: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not directly compare floating point numbers with `==`, but check instead that they are really close:

```
j=1;
dt = 1E-05;
a=[];
while dt*j <=20
    if abs(mod(dt*j,1)) < 1e-10
        a=round([a;[dt*j,j]]);
    end
j=j+1;
end
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I used this == comparison before but this problem never appears until today...

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing there is some strange rounding errors. I tried your code and I am getting the same result. One approach would be rather than using mod(dt*j,1) ==0, use mod(dt*j,1) < dt or mod(dt*j,1) < thresh, where you can set a threshold that is close enough to zero that it will do the trick.

From wikipedia's page on the double-precision floating number format page, it says:
1.0000000000000002, the smallest number > 1 . From that I would extrapolate that using a double, you get a numerical resolution of about 2E-16. Therefore you could use a threshold of 2E-15 and be more than safe.

Comment: The numerical resolution is given by `eps`, and indeed it is about 2e-16